# Moving dirty records to a new table in Talend 6.1

Tags: error-handling, talend

I have a Talend job. Whenever it encounters any error, the job gets killed.

I don't want the job to die on error, rather it should push all the error records to a different table and continue processing the good records and complete the job.

I am not aware how to I go about handling this. Can someone suggest me on this?

[image]

This is what i am doing. I was able get the rejects outflow, but in this my good records are not getting populated in my main table. Only the rejected records are getting populated in mt error table.

Comment: what components are you having in your job. mostly components have a checkbox Die on Error. if you uncheck that, the component will log the error,  and still continue..moving error records in a different table depends on how you design the job. Also you can catch exceptions using tlogcatcher.

Comment: @garpitmzn I have edited the question by adding the screen shot of what I have done. Kindly check the same.

Comment: its difficult to comment without knowing what is the basis of rejecting records. If your requirement is solved and it works, then please go ahead.

Comment: I am rejecting rows if there is any issue with the data. Say for example, a record has a field whose length is more than expected, then it should continue with the good records and move this particular record to another table along with the error code.